# combining jquery functions ready and live

Tags: function, live, ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel='box']").colorbox();
                });
```

and

```
jQuery('a[href*=#]').live('click',function() { ...etc...
```

total NOOB question:
I have these two functions in JQuery...

How do I combine them ?

`a[href*=#]` is a slideshow presentation and `a[rel='box']` is for a colorbox to open... 
one or the other works but not both together.

That is what I get for trying to "cut and paste" code...

the Jquery is loaded

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
```

in the HEAD section

I even tried to add:

```
 jQuery(function(){
 if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.colorbox)) {
    jQuery("a").live('click',function(){
         jQuery(this).colorbox();
     });
 }
 });
```

but this didn't work either...

This is where I got the slideshow... www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/ colorbox is loaded, but doesn't work on individual pictures...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated and thanks!

Comment: If you're new to jQuery you shouldn't be using `live`. It's been deprecated since 1.7.

Comment: thanks for your patience... http://www.edparton.com/hope/demo.html is the page

Comment: call for colorbox is at about line #337

Comment: http://haitioneyear.org/ is the effect I am trying to achieve

Comment: What am I supposed to click on to see the colorbox?

Comment: <div class="thumb"><a href="images/img7.jpg" rel="box" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee."><img src="images/img7-mini.jpg"> </a></div>

Comment: for the haitioneyear.org it is one of the pics below the slideshow

Comment: I think you have a conflict with jQuery, there's an error in the console on the `$(document).ready()` line, because `$` is undefined.

Comment: I copied that colorbox code from a working installation of mine... but the custom.js is where the conflict is coming from

Comment: I think your copy of `jquery.min.js` is corrupted, it doesn't define `$`.

Comment: It ends with `jQuery.noConflict();`, that prevents defining `$`. So you have to write `jQuery(document).ready()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: that is interesting, there is also a jquery.noconflict in the custom.js file??

Comment: You can write `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });`. Then you can use `$` inside the function.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: $.noConflict();
  jquery(document).ready(function($){
   
   $("a[rel='box']").colorbox();
     });  this doesn't work either

Comment: should I put this on the page or in the custom.js file?

Comment: I can't believe it is 3:00am and you are still with me!

Comment: `jQuery` not `jquery`. It should be wherever you need to define your document.ready code, that's usually the main page.

Comment: Do you know how to see errors in the JS console? You really need to learn how to debug, you can't depend on someone to hold your hand through all this.

Comment: I did not notice the jQuery... ha! but I changed it and the colorbox still does not work

Comment: you are perfectly right... how do I see errors in the JS console?

Comment: You can't write `$.noConflict()` after you already have `jQuery.noConflict()` in jquery.min.js. How many times do I have to tell you that this prevents using the `$` abbreviation?

Comment: What browser are you using? There should be a developer menu to let you get into the web inspector.

Comment: thanks, I found the CONSOLE to help debug in chrome ctrl shft j

Comment: GENIUS !  I found  the $ no.Conflict() and took it out, Now IT Works!

Comment: $.noConflict() and the small "q" is what it was!

Comment: really! thank you SO MUCH for sticking with a noob ... you have been an excellent teacher

Comment: Looks like some minor style glitches in the colorbox, the X button is cut off.

Comment: thanks again... that little X button is easy to fix... thanks

Comment: Can you please add your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list of questions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was defining $ in jQuery NOT an A conflict with READY and LIVE...

I think your copy of jquery.min.js is corrupted, it doesn't define $.

Your jQuery script ends with jQuery.noConflict();, that prevents defining $.

So you have to write jQuery(document).ready() instead of $(document).ready()

You can't write $.noConflict() after you already have jQuery.noConflict() in jquery.min.js.

SOLUTION:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){            
        $("a[rel='box']").colorbox();
                });
```

NOT:

```
// cannot below use if have jQuery.noConflict(); !  use above notice large Q //
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel='box']").colorbox();
        });
```

THANKS! Barmar!